# What does the '@' mean when prefixed to Windows font face name?

Tags: winapi, fonts, gdi

With `EnumFontFamiliesEx`, I get two instances of some fonts, the second of which has '@' prefixed to the face name in the `LOGFONT`.  For example, I get "MS PMincho" and "@MS PMincho".  Yet for other fonts, I just get a single instance, like "Arial".  What does the at-sign mean in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are fonts specifically optimized for vertical text. [See for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194859.aspx). If your application does not support writing from top to bottom, you should probably filter out such fonts.

Comment: To be clear, they are not _optimized_ for vertical text, they _enable_ it.  Fonts without the @ simply aren't capable of vertical text as shown in the example.